# Display footer on video background

Tags: html, css, video

I have this problem when adding a footer on top of a background video in HTML. It simply displays the text in the top right corner of the page.

Here is my code.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Teststyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background-wrap">
     <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Video not supported
     </video>
   </div>     
   <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
   </div>
  </body>       
 </html>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
       *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        }

        .background-wrap {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -1000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #video-bg-elem {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000;
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .content p {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            color: white;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .content h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 65px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 303;
            color: #fff;
            padding-top: 5%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 1rem;
            background-color: #efefef;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

If you could tell me why its not working I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you update an image of what you view

Comment: State what you expected and the issue you got precisely

Comment: i got the same issue the footer background is always transparent,changing the video element z-index to some negative value solved the problem for me.Try adding "z-index:-1000;" in #video-bg-elem css.